# Determine which renderer is used for vertex shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, gpu

Apple's OpenGL Shader Builder let's you drop in your vertex (or fragment) shader and it will link and validate it then tell you which GL_RENDERER is used for that shader. For me it either shows: Apple Software Renderer (in red because it means the shader will be dog slow) or AMD Radeon HD 6970M OpenGL Engine (i.e. my gpu's renderer which I usually want to run the shader).

How can I also determine this at runtime in my own software?

**Edit:**
Querying GL_RENDERER in my CPU code always seems to return AMD Radeon HD 6970M OpenGL Engine regardless of where I place it in the draw loop even though I'm using a shader that OpenGL Shader Builder says is running on Apple Software Renderer (and I believe it because it's very slow). Is it a matter of querying GL_RENDERER at just the right time? If so, when?

Answer (score 0):

The renderer used is tied to the OpenGL context and a proper OpenGL implementation should not switch the renderer inbetween. Of course a OpenGL implementation may be built on some infrastructure that dynamically switches between backend renderers, but this must then reflect to the frontend context in renderer string that identifies this.

So what you do is indeed the correct method.